# AS3 SoundChannel losing decimal places on SoundTransform.volume value

Tags: actionscript-3, soundchannel

I am trying to make a volume control for audio calibration. We were hoping to go to a 0.1% increment for altering the volume on a SoundChannel's volume.

This is my code, and my output.

```
var transform:SoundTransform = _soundChannel.soundTransform;
transform.volume = 0.999;
_soundChannel.soundTransform = transform;

trace('transform ' +transform.volume); // 0.999
trace('channel ' +_soundChannel.soundTransform.volume); // 0.99
```

The `SoundTransform` Object is retaining the 3rd decimal place, but as soon as I assign it to the `soundTransform` property of my `SoundChannel`, it's reducing the specificity of my volume.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: .99 is a 1% increment - This is probably a limitation of flash player (just guessing), I can't see any real world situation needing volume precision in the thousands - do you actually have one or this just learning/testing?

Comment: It's a real use-case, unfortunately.. We are creating a tone-test application for audiologists, and this portion is to calibrate exactly what volume the system & mixer needs to be for each frequency of a tone.

Comment: We are able to achieve "benchmark" levels for perfect hearing as is... but it's using something ridiculously low like 7% speaker volume and 6% on the SoundTransform itself. (iOS App)

Comment: the thousandth increment would have just allowed us to use something like 20% system and 2.1% `SoundTransform.volume`

Comment: It may indeed be a limitation of flash player. This use case may be better handled via processing or openframeworks.

Comment: Yea, your best bet may be to use a native component for the setting of the actual audio.  It's pretty easy in AS3/AIR to use a custom component written in object-c that could set the audio more precisely.

Comment: Yes, we already are also controlling the system (phone) volume as well. Just wanted to add that extra level or precision. Looks like it may not be possible. Very strange that a `SoundTransform` accepts the `.999` value, yet the `SoundChannel` does not.

Comment: The strangeness is probably because the value is stored as a normal number (so it can accept any valid number value),  but when it goes to set the actual volume it's rounding to the nearest valid value.   That's my theory anyway...

Comment: Great point. I think you hit the nail on the head.